# Copy spreadsheet from Downloads folder locally into a main sheet on a different spreadsheet

Tags: vba, excel, download

I've hit a roadblock and I can't figure it out for the life of me. Here is what I am trying to accomplish:

- A program I use exports a snapshot of the data into a spreadsheet (.xls) into the **Downloads** folder locally.
- I need to copy the data of sheet1 of this spreadsheet (**without opening it**) into the main spreadsheet I have saved elsewhere which is the "main" sheet and **open**. I have a macro button on the main sheet that runs this code.

The caveat is that I have to make the Downloads folder dynamic in that it is not a specific username, because it is going to be used by multiple users.

This code works perfectly for 1 person:

```vb
Sub sbCopyingAFile()
Dim MyFile As String, Str As String, MyDir As String, Wb As Workbook
Dim Rws As Long, Rng As Range
Set Wb = ThisWorkbook
MyDir = "C:\Users\{My_Username}\Downloads\"
MyFile = Dir(MyDir & "*.xls")
ChDir MyDir
Application.ScreenUpdating = 0
Application.DisplayAlerts = 0

Do While MyFile <> ""
    Workbooks.Open (MyFile)
    With Worksheets(1)
        Rws = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Set Rng = Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(Rws, 19))
        Rng.Copy Wb.Worksheets("DUMP").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 0)
        ActiveWorkbook.Close True
    End With
    MyFile = Dir()
Loop
On Error Resume Next
    Kill "C:\Users\{My_Username}\Downloads\*.*"
On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```

This was my last attempt at getting any Downloads folder, not specific to a username:

```
Sub sbCopyingAFile()
Dim MyFile As String, Str As String, Wb As Workbook, MyDir As String
'Dim fso
Dim Rws As Long, Rng As Range
'Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set Wb = ThisWorkbook
MyDir = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").specialfolders("Downloads")
'MyDir = "C:\Users\{My_Username}\Downloads\"
MyFile = Dir(MyDir & "*.xls")
ChDir MyDir
Application.ScreenUpdating = 0
Application.DisplayAlerts = 0

Do While MyFile <> ""
Workbooks.Open (MyFile)
With Worksheets(1)
    Rws = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set Rng = Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(Rws, 19))
    Rng.Copy Wb.Worksheets("DUMP").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 0)
    ActiveWorkbook.Close True
End With
MyFile = Dir()
Loop
On Error Resume Next
'Kill "C:\Users\{My_Username}\Downloads\*.*"
On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Environ$("Username")` to get the current username. This will return a string.

So your path would look something along the lines of:

```
"C:\Users\" & Environ$("Username") & "\Downloads\"
```

Comment: @braX Don't you hate that? :D

Comment: Question sits for 45 minutes with no answers and then 2 people simultaneously... It's ok tho - you need the points more :P

Comment: You can also use `Environ$("UserProfile") & "\Downloads\"` in case the user set up their profiles in a weird place that isn't `"C:\Users"`

Comment: @Thuunder Looks like your line with `MyDir = "C:\Users\" & Environ$("Username") & "\Downloads\"`

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `Environ$("UserProfile") & "\Downloads\"` in case the user set up their profiles in a weird place that isn't `"C:\Users"`